# "Can't" or "couldn't"

Tags: word-in-context

In the phrase below:

> I know sometimes life can be extremely tough and make you feel just
>   like if you can’t count on anyone else.

...which is basically a literal translation of the same phrase in Portuguese, the use of "can't count on anyone else" is grammatically correct (or even acceptable) or should I use "couldn't count on anyone else" instead?

Also, can I really use the "if" in...

> make you feel just like if you can't count on anyone else.

the way I did or should I omit it and use simply...

> make you feel just like you can't count on anyone else.

Comment: The present tense *feel* needs *can't*. Use **could** to transpose to *past* tense: "I felt like I **could**n't count on anyone else." And its "like" or "as if"; you can't mix and match

Comment: I'm immensely thankful to you for helping me with this question.

Comment: Please, just to be sure I really understand your explanations, if you have some time available just confirm if the sentences below in the present tense are now correct:

I know sometimes life can be extremely tough and make you feel just like you can’t count on anyone else. (no "if" after "like")

I know sometimes life can be extremely tough and make you feel just as if you can’t count on anyone else. (use of "as if" instead of "like if")

Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, your versions are correct. Present-tense *can* (meaning "is able to") has past tense *could* (meaning "was able to"),  but *could* also has other modal senses, i.e.,  meanings not related to tense. The same goes for *will*/*would* and *shall*/*should*. This seems to me a difficult area of idiomatic usage.

Comment: Really appreciate it. Thanks a lot.